# Cannot get node-apn to connect

Tags: node.js, apn-node

I'm trying to make a connection to APNs. It simply won't connect. I get variations of:

```
  apn Socket error occurred +609ms { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

and

```
apn Connection error occurred before TLS Handshake +0ms
```

This is for a Passbook pass. Not an app. I'm using Passbook certificates.

My code is:

```
var apns = require('apn');

var root = process.cwd();

var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    cert: root + '/certs/new/cert.pem',                 /* Certificate file path */
    certData: null,                   /* String or Buffer containing certificate data, if supplied uses this instead of cert file path */
    key:  root + '/certs/new/key.pem',                  /* Key file path */
    keyData: null,                    /* String or Buffer containing key data, as certData */
    passphrase: 'secret',                 /* A passphrase for the Key file */
    ca: null,                         /* String or Buffer of CA data to use for the TLS connection */
    gateway: 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com',/* gateway address */
    port: 2195,                       /* gateway port */
    enhanced: true,                   /* enable enhanced format */
    errorCallback: undefined,         /* Callback when error occurs function(err,notification) */
    cacheLength: 100                  /* Number of notifications to cache for error purposes */
};

var apnsConnection = new apns.Connection(options);

var myDevice = new apns.Device('token');

var note = new apns.Notification();

note.payload = {};
note.device = myDevice;

apnsConnection.sendNotification(note);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I mixed up my certificates. I'm sure I tried swapping them earlier but obviously didn't.

---

**cert**: Your app cert.
**key**: Apple's WWDR

Answer (score 0):

are you behind a proxy? that could be the issue (at least it is often in my case)

Comment: then im sorry, not easy to help you here ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Try the following structure : Read the `.cert` and `.key` files manually and set them as `certData` and `keyData` property, respectivelly. Here is the core :

```
var key = root + '/certs/new/key.pem'
var cert = root + '/certs/new/cert.pem';

var certData = fs.readFileSync(cert, encoding='ascii');
var keyData = fs.readFileSync(key, encoding='ascii');

var apnsConnection = new apns.Connection({
    certData: certData,
    keyData: keyData,
    gateway: 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com',
    port: 2195,
    ... /* other configs of course */
});
```